# Installing external packages into Canopy Python using easy_install as non-admin

Tags: enthought

I am user of a Windows computer without admin rights and just installed Canopy Python from Enthought (and I was really excited that I was able to do this without admin rights). I would now like to install an external package (that is not available in Canopy Python as an academic user). The instructions on the [support page from Enthought](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-external-packages-into-Canopy-Python) suggest that to install an external package, we can just open a command window, make sure that Canopy Python is on the SHELL path, and then "follow standard Python installation procedures from the command line," with the suggested approach being to use easy_install. However, as a non-admin, when trying to use easy_install, a dialog box pops up requesting a admin username/password (which I do not have as a regular user). Does anyone know if it is possible to use easy_install as a non-admin or if there is an alternative solution to install external packages for non-admin users for Canopy Python?

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible that you are picking up the `easy_install` of another Python distribution on your machine?

The default location of `easy_install` in Canopy is

`C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts\easy_install`

Please try using the full address explicitly and see if that works, in theory you should not need admin rights.

**Update:** The problem is due to one of the heuristics used by Windows UAC to determine if an application requires privilege escalation: If there is the word "setup" or "install" in the name, it will prompt for elevation. (See the answer below by Mona regarding which files to rename.) It's probably easier to rename easy_install, and use it to install `pip` (`easy install pip`), and use that instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you should be able to use a terminal that sets the required environment variables for you by choosing `Start Menu > All Programs > Enthought Canopy > Canopy command prompt`.  You can then run the scripts installed by Canopy, without having to explicitly use the full path.

Comment: I just tried explicitly typing the full path to the Enthought Canopy easy_install path suggested above and received the same dialog message that requests an admin username/password (just in case, I tried both with a regular command prompt and the Canopy command prompt). I also have tried just using easy_install with the Canopy command prompt and the same admin username/password dialog appears (in fact, this is actually what I had tried first).

Answer (score 2):

As an update, after searching some more on User Access Control (UAC) on windows (and coming across something that mentioned that having "install" in the name of a program may cause problems, but I do not know for sure if this was the cause of a problem in my case), I just tried the following "hack" which worked for me (but perhaps someone else can suggest a more elegant solution or can provide more feedback as to why this works):

1. Go to C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts\
2. Rename easy_install.exe to easy.exe
3. Rename easy_install-script.py to easy-script.py
4. Run "C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts\easy.exe PackageName" from the command line.
5. (Wait for package to be installed and check for success by opening Canopy Python and trying to import the package.)

Some additional comments: I received an error if I didn't perform step #3 above (renaming the .py file as well). Also, I needed to type the full path to easy.exe in this case from the command line.

This worked for me (and I can use the external package), but again, my guess is that there should be a more "official" solution that does not require renaming easy_install.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: And what firewall and antivirus software?

Comment: A colleague had a similar issue in the past: the problem is not coming from a firewall or antivirus. It is one of the heuristics used by Windows UAC to determine if an application requires privilege escalation. If there is the word "setup" or "install" in the name, it will prompt for elevation.

Comment: And easy_install.exe calls easy_install-script.py. In fact, the easy install executable looks for a .py file named <easy_install_exe_name>-script.py, which explains why step 3 was necessary. All that being said, you don't need the .exe: you can run easy_install-script.py directly as in "python path/to/Scripts/easy_install-script.py install package-name" to install package-name.